# Average Cost Threshold Protocol with Minimum Thresholds: How to find the price?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, efficiency

The protocol is defined [here](http://blog.felixbreuer.net/2013/01/20/average-cost-threshold-protocol.html), but I'll give a summary here.

Okay, so a number of agents want a certain public good to be constructed (a public good is something like a book, a program, or a statue, something that can optionally benefit everyone once constructed.) It costs $P$ to construct this good. The agents each give an interval that they are willing to pay. Agent $i$'s interval is $[m_i,M_i]$. (In the case of a rational agent, $m_i=0$, but if the agent is somewhat altruistic, $m_i>0$. It has been proven that $M_i$ will always be how much value a rational agent $i$ expects to extract from the public good.)

Now, in this protocol, each person pays the same price $p$, or $m_i$, whichever is greater, or pays nothing at all if $p > M_i$. (Those who pay get access to the good, those who don't are excluded from the good.) What I am trying to do is find the minimum $p$, such that the total amount paid (let's call it $F(p)$) is equal to or greater than $P$, efficiently.

If all $m_i$ are $0$ and there are $n$ agents, I can do it $\mathcal O(n \log n)$. I first sort the agents by $M_i$. Then starting with the agent with least $M_i$, I figure out how much funds will be available with $p=M_i$. If $F(M_i) \gt P$, than $M_i$ is the minimum $p$. Otherwise, we go to the next agent, and so on. $F(M_i)$ can be calculated in $\mathcal O (n)$, by multiplying $M_i$ by how many agents come after (or are) agent $i$ (for each agent $j$ that comes after $i$, $M_j \ge M_i$. Since $p=M_i$, not $p>M_j$, and agent $j$ pays $p=M_i$.) (Note, I've left out the analysis for when $p$ is between the $M_i$'s; it doesn't change the it too much.)

My question is, how does one solve this problem efficiently in general, when the $m_i$ may not be $0$?

[image: See http://blog.felixbreuer.net/2013/02/06/digital-goods.html]

Note: Sorry if I didn't phrase this clearly. Feel free to ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: Crowdfunding has reached CS/mathematics, it seems! Cool! FWIW, if the motivation is to solve the problem fast in practice, looking beyond $\Theta(n \log n)$ may not be worth the time. Improving the algorithm you have (constant factors, average case) may return more on your investment.

Comment: @Raphael mostly theoretical at this point. (That said, this protocol for funding is much more efficient than open source and closed source, in a certain technical yet broad sense. I'm surprised it hasn't arisen naturally.)

Comment: @Raphael Also, has crowdfunding been more prevalent other places?

Comment: @PyRulez I'm not sure I understand the example you gave with all $m_i = 0$. If all the $M_i$ are sufficiently large, then shouldn't the optimal $p = P/n$? I.e.: if 10 people are willing to pay between up to 100 for something where $P = 20$, then everyone should just pay 2, right?

Comment: @mhum That would be correct. The intuition though is that the $M_i$ are all rather *small* compared to $P$. In the image, all the $M_i$ are below $\$100$, while $P=\$1.0$m ($\$1000000$). (Its not like everyone is willing to pay for the *whole statue*.)

Comment: @PyRulez Ok. But even in that case, if $n$ is sufficiently large, then you could still have a case where $p$ is less than all $M_i$'s. My larger point is that the method outlined seems to only produce $p = M_j$ for some $j$ when, in general, I don't think the optimum $p$ is necessarily equal to any $M_j$.

Comment: @mhum To simplify things, I didn't consider the possibility of $p$ being between (or below) the $M_j$'s. This doesn't change the analysis significantly. Also, $n$ isn't sufficiently large either. (The idea is that $n$ will slowly grow over time, and then your analysis would be correct. In the beginning, will small $n$, $p=\frac Pn$ won't be possible.)

Comment: @PyRulez. Ok, fair enough. Thanks for the clarification. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: @mhum (In fact, there is no guarantee that there is *any* possible $p$ (in which case the algorithm would return "no solution").)

Answer (score 2):

There are two standard kinds of approaches to this sort of problem.

1. Check out [segment trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) and [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), and see if either of them are useful here (e.g., by augmenting the data structure).
2. Explore a [sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).  In this sort of algorithm, we envision $p$ increasing from 0 upward as time progresses, and at each point in time, we keep track of the set of all intervals that contain $p$.  Thus, when $p$ hits the left endpoint of an interval, we add it to the set; when it reaches the right endpoint, we remove it from the set.  You can store the set as a balanced binary tree data structure, and then make it [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) using standard [path copying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Path_copying) techniques.  Now that you have this persistent data structure that captures all points in time, often you can find a way to solve your problem fairly rapidly.  Crucially, the tree will be of size $O(n \lg n)$ and depth $O(\lg n)$, so accesses are fast.

I haven't explored either of those approaches in the context of your particular problem, but these are two general techniques that are often useful for problems of this sort.

Comment: The problem is the number of possible prices could be on the order of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is how far I got. Adding each agent is $\mathcal O(n)$, for a total of $\mathcal O(n^2)$, but spread out (the application I had in mind would involve agents coming one at a time).

If you have no agents, start with an empty linked list. If you have $n$ agents, you will already have a solution of $p_{old}$ for $n-1$ agents, as well as an old linked list, as well as our new agent, agent $i$.

The linked list has elements of the form $(\Delta P_j,m_j,M_j)$, where $\Delta P_j = P - F(M_j)$, a.k.a., how much more money is needed if $p=M_j$. It is sorted by $M_j$, smallest first.

So we traverse our linked list, starting with $(\Delta P_j,m_j,M_j)$. If $M_i \ge M_j$, decrease $\Delta P_j$ accordingly. If $\Delta P_j = 0$, $p=M_j$, then the rest of the linked list is discarded (including agent $j$'s node), and we end. If $\Delta P_j \gt 0$, continue traversing. If $M_i < M_j$,  keep a reference to $j$'s node. Now traverse the rest of the list to determine $\Delta P_i$. If $\Delta P_i = 0$, then $p=M_i$, and throw out all nodes after and including agent $j$. If $\Delta P_i \gt 0$, then before $j$ insert a node $(\Delta P_i,m_i,M_i)$, and $p=p_{old}$.